# How to nest effects within lmer?

Tags: r, lme4

I'm playing around with models.

If I run a basic GLM:

```
summary(glm(nfc~nform+p+namount+lime+pH+year, data=parkglm,family=gaussian()))
```

I get results that include year as an explanatory variable:

[image]

However, I need year to be nested in another factor, "period". There are 17 years, each year falls within one of two periods. I tried this using lme4 and lmer.

```
anova(lmer(nfc~nform+p+namount+lime+pH+(year|period), data=parkglm))
```

That gave me the below output which seems pretty reasonable, however you'll see that year or period aren't listed. I assume they've been controlled for, but I'm interested in their effects. I'm very iffy on nesting with in the lmer package.

[image: lmer output]

I appreciate there might be *alot* wrong going on here and apologies for that. If it's just a mess, fine, don't be afraid to say! I'm new to linear models in r and have struggled to find the info I need in a manner I can implement.

Here is a slight snapshot of the top of the data with types of data in each column.

- Period = categoric and is either "pre" or "post"
- Year = continuous
- Plot = ignore
- Nform = categoric
- namount =   continuous
- p = binary/categoric (0 or 1)
- k = ignore
- lime = binary /
  categoric (0 or 1)
- ph:nfc = all continuous

[image: data snap.]

Answer (score 2):

This formula is for a mixed-effects model with a random intercept for "period",
assuming that each observation is grouped by that variable.
Note that "year" was included as a fixed effect.

```
library(lme4)
summary(fm <- lmer(nfc ~ nform + p + namount + lime + pH + year + (1|period), data = parkglm))
```

However the model may not be appropriate given the low number of categories
in the variable "period".

I suggest you take a look to some references about linear models and think about strategies to model your data, perhaps building categories or exploring different models. Two
good manuscripts you may be interested:

[Winter, B. (2013). Linear models and linear mixed effects models in R
with linguistic applications. arXiv:1308.5499.](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1308.5499.pdf)

[Douglas Bates, Martin Maechler, Ben Bolker, Steve Walker (2015).
Fitting Linear Mixed-Effects Models Using lme4. Journal of Statistical
Software, 67(1), 1-48. doi:10.18637/jss.v067.i01.](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v067i01)

Comment: Thank you very much. I saw your reply the other day but have taken some time to digest it and learn more around the topic.

More broadly, I've always struggled a bit with the wording in this area of the stats, especially the definition of "random" as the periods themself are not "random", but I see that in this model they need to be seen as that.

thanks again.